# Unable to open a public linkedin profile in a browser

Tags: user-interface, amazon-web-services, linkedin-api, gnome

I am using Ubuntu Gnome GUI on my AWS server, in which I have installed Firefox and chrome browsers. When I try to open a public LinkedIn profile it asks me to sign up first.[image]Why I cannot view public LinkedIn profiles using my browser?

Comment: Any updates?? Can you please share how you achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn has probably implemented some sort of block for all IP addresses on the Amazon IP range.

Generally this is done to prevent automated programs from scraping data from the public LinkedIn site.

Ticketmaster does something similar.